# R, hclust : How to create a representative for each cluster?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hclust

I've got my clusterisation done, now, I want to use it to replace missing values.
My idea is to compute a representative for each cluster then replace missing values according to that representative.
The problem is... I don't really know how to do that.

I searched about it and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400720/r-cluster-analysis-with-hclust-how-to-get-the-cluster-representatives), which seems to almost answer my issue (finding a representative would also work for me), but I don't understand enough of it to use it.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(TSclust)
set.seed(1)
df = data.table(
  "Time" = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  "1" = runif(5),
  "2" = runif(5),
  "3" = runif(5),
  "4" = runif(5),
  "5" = runif(5),
  "6" = runif(5))

clusters = hclust(diss(ts(df[,-1]), "EUCL"))
tree = cutree(clusters, 3)

rep = df%>%
  gather(key = ID,value = Conso, -Time)%>%
  mutate(Cluster = as.vector(sapply(tree, FUN = rep,times = 5)))%>%
  group_by(Cluster, Time)%>%
  summarise(Conso = mean(Conso))
```

Here's something close to my actual data, and here's some naive way to compute some representatives.

Is this actually an ok way to do it ? Do you know a way to extract those representatives from *clusters* ?

Comment: When it comes to time series, many researchers argue that a mean centroid is a poor representative, but it is definitely a possibility, and you're calculating it correctly. You could read Section 3 in [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dtwclust/vignettes/dtwclust.pdf) if you want more information.

Comment: In general, it is worth going over this: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MissingData.html

Comment: If you have missing values, how good will your clustering be? Its distance based, and the distances suffer from missing values. So you'd want to first solve the missing values...